# What part of the sed manpage explains how to delete lines in a file

Tags: sed, manpage

`sed -e '4,17d' filename` deletes lines 4 through 17 in the file filename. I wondered how they explain such a thing in the manpage. I looked it up the manpage. However I don't see how people are getting information for the job. Which parts of the `sed` manpage do they explain how to make the command combination like `sed -e '4,17d' filename`??

Comment: the text on " 3.1 'sed' script overview" seems close... were you looking at `info sed`? or just the summary-reference `man sed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with:

```
-e script, --expression=script
      add the script to the commands to be executed
```

And:

```
COMMAND SYNOPSIS
   This is just a brief synopsis of sed commands to serve as a reminder to
   those who already know sed; other documentation (such  as  the  texinfo
   document) must be consulted for fuller descriptions.
...
Commands which accept address ranges
...
   d      Delete pattern space.  Start next cycle.
```

In the section on **Addresses**:

> Sed commands can be given with ... with  two  addresses,  in  which
>   case the command will be    executed for all input lines which match
>   the inclusive range  of  lines    starting  from  the first address
>   and continuing to the second address. Three things to note about address ranges: the  syntax  is  addr1,addr2  (i.e.,  the  addresses  are separated by a comma); the line which
>   addr1    matched will always be accepted, even if addr2 selects an
>   earlier line;    and  if  addr2 is a regexp, it will not be tested
>   against the line that    addr1 matched.

And finally:

```
The full documentation for sed is maintained as a Texinfo manual.  If
the info and sed programs are properly installed at your site, the
command

      info sed

should give you access to the complete manual.
```

From http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sed.1.html. `info sed` also contains examples.

Comment: I followed a lot of links in manual. Then I think this is a complete documentation. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Introduction

Comment: There are a lot of broken links on the sed homepage. http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed`, like many other GNU programs, is not fully documented in the `man` page. The full documentation is available through `info` (`info sed`) or [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/).